# Attach AJAX fetched value with Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to attach AJAX fetched value with [Select2](https://select2.org). My JavaScript code is like below.

```
(function($) {  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".volunteer").on("click", function (event) {
      let element_id = event.target.id;
      // Check if select is already loaded
      if (!$(this).has("select").length) {
        var cellEle = $(this);

        // Populate select element
        cellEle.html(`<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"></select>`);

        // Initialise select2
        let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({
          ajax: {
            url: "/wordpressbosta/matt/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
              return { 
                q: element_id,
                        action: 'get_data'
                    };
            },
            type: "post",
            processResults: function(data) {              
              var options = [];
              if ( data ) {
                $.each( data, function( index, text ) {
                  options.push( { text: text  } );
                });
              }
              return {
                results: options
              };
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

I am getting output like below.

[image]

If I click on any value, it is not set to the select box. Values are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select2 requires that each option has an `id` property and a `text` property. In the code above the `processResults` method is returning an array of objects which contain only a `text` property, without an `id`. When adding objects to the array in `processResults` an `id` should be included:

```js
options.push({ id: id, text: text });
```

Details on this format can be found at https://select2.org/data-sources/formats. As per this page:

> Blank `id`s or an `id` with a value of `0` are not permitted.

You could either use `text` as the `id` value if it's unique, or use `index + 1` (+ 1 to avoid a value of 0). In the below example code `text` is used.

```js
processResults: function(data) {
  var options = [];
  if (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, text) {
      options.push({ id: text, text: text });
    });
  }
  return {
    results: options
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris C. It is working like Magic. But my select needs 2 clicks to display values as drop down elements. How can I get it in 1 click ? How can I place X (cross sign) right side of the value ?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lslnH.png.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. The solution to clicking twice is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70419682/jquery-select2-with-wordpress, call `selectEle.select2('open');` after select2 is setup (after line 36 on your code in the question).  As far as I'm aware there is no select2 option to move the multi-choice `×` from the left to the right, but you should be able to achieve this with some CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Chris C. How can I disable `Searching...`  text ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fKnncKRmn4WrY7q697Zld1IswiB4CFjR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @abuabu I suggest refering to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55827285/change-text-searching-in-jquery-select2 to change the text. Or if you'd like to hide it then doing so with CSS

Comment: Hello @Chris C. Now I would like to fetch value using AJAX for select2, but some of them will be prefilled(preselected) in the select box and some of them will be on drop down list. How can I do that ? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest checking the documentation for preselecting values at https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#default-pre-selected-values, this should give you the information you need